# How do I fix the behavior of the braces in the VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The issue happened to be with auto-closing brackets.

[Here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avb4u.png) the screenshot of the brackets before I press the enter
and [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRu5I.png) will show the behavior of the braces after. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAYau.png) are my expectations of how this is supposed to work

In advance, thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:
Settings -> Text Editor -> Auto Indent -> Set this to "Full".

This will create an Enter in between the two braces.

Comment: I have it set by default

Answer (score 0):

Find this line in your settings.json. If it's empty like mine was, this is possibly the cause of your frustration.

```
"editor.language.brackets": [],
```

Change to:

```
"editor.language.brackets": [
    ["[", "]"],
    ["(", ")"],
    ["{", "}"]
],
```

Hope this helps!